# Dúvida sobre classes e métodos em Python

Tags: python, funções, classes, método

Tenho uma dúvida, não consigo fazer um exercício de classes e métodos.

> 2 - Crie a classe "Data" com os atributos: dia, mes, e ano. E crie os métodos "setarData(recebe dia, mes e ano)" e "imprimir("ex: 03/08/2017")". O Construtor deve inicializar com 01/01/1970. USE PARÂMETROS OPCIONAIS.

O programa deve começar com 01/01/1970 e deve imprimir a data que o usuário inserir. Ex: 03/08/2017

Imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO85v.jpg

- IMAGEM ATUALIZADA (Não consigo importar a classe no programa principal): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgE1g.jpg

O que eu consegui fazer, travei nessa parte...:

```
class Data:
def __init__(self, d = 1, m = 1, a = 1970):
    self.dia = d
    self.mes = m
    self.ano = a

def setarData(self, d = 3, m = 8, a = 2017):
    self.dia = 
    self.mes = m
    self.ano = a
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Queria a ajuda de vocês pra resolver o exercício. Tenho muitas dúvidas de como se cria classes e métodos e tal. E gostaria de ajuda...

Comment: Mas descreva o que exatamente você não está entendendo.

Comment: Eu não sei como continuar. E nem sei se o que eu fiz está correto

Comment: Você não sabe fazer o `imprimir()`?  O enunciado está meio esquisito, é isso mesmo? Mesmo que dá para entender é meio ambíguo.

Comment: Sim, o enunciado é esse mesmo...

Comment: Atualizei o tópico com a imagem do exercício. Tá hospedado no Imgur... Espero que entendam agora.

Comment: Ainda não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: Exceto a indentação errada dentro da classe, a definição dos métodos está correta. Aliás, no método `setarData` faltou o `d` em `self.dia = d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece muito simples, você está quase lá. Basta corrigir um erro no método `setarData()`, como notado pelo Anderson...

```
def setarData(self, d = 3, m = 8, a = 2017):
    self.dia = d
    self.mes = m
    self.ano = a
```

E adicionar o método `imprimir()`:

```
def imprimir(self):
    print '%02d/%02d/%04' % (self.dia, self.mes, self.ano)
```

Se eu fosse você removeria os parâmetros opcionais do método `setarData()` pois aparentemente não foi solicitado e também não me parece fazer muito sentido. Ele ficaria assim:

```
def setarData(self, d, m, a):
    self.dia = d
    self.mes = m
    self.ano = a
```

Comment: E como eu importaria a minha classe no meu programa principal em outro arquivo .py?

Comment: Adicionei uma foto no post principal, deem uma olhada.

Comment: Coloque sua classe ou método em um arquivo de nome simples, sem acentos ou hifens e com extensão `.py` (`codigo.py`, por exemplo) e, do seu programa principal chame `import codigo` e `d = codigo.Data()` ou `d = codigo.Data(10, 8, 2017)` e `d.imprimir()`.